# Error in Cordova Installation

Tags: cordova, ionic2

**When I install on Mac using sudo it seems to install but it really is not as seen by my attempt to get a version number.

This is affecting my ability to use ionic 1 and ionic 2. I cannot use 'ionic emulate ios'**

```
$ sudo npm install -g cordova
npm WARN deprecated npmconf@2.1.2: this package has been reintegrated into npm and is now out of date with respect to npm
/usr/local/bin/cordova ->    /usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/bin/cordova
cordova@6.0.0 /usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova
├── underscore@1.7.0
├── q@1.0.1
├── ansi@0.3.1
├── nopt@3.0.1 (abbrev@1.0.7)
├── update-notifier@0.5.0 (is-npm@1.0.0, semver-diff@2.1.0, string-length@1.0.1, chalk@1.1.1, repeating@1.1.3, configstore@1.4.0, latest-version@1.0.1)
└── cordova-lib@6.0.0 (valid-identifier@0.0.1, opener@1.4.1, properties-parser@0.2.3, semver@4.3.6, nopt@3.0.6, dep-graph@1.1.0, shelljs@0.3.0, xcode@0.8.0, npmconf@2.1.2, request@2.47.0, cordova-serve@1.0.0, aliasify@1.9.0, tar@1.0.2, cordova-app-hello-world@3.10.0, init-package-json@1.9.3, cordova-js@4.1.3, npm@2.14.19)
```

**However When I try to get the version number I get an error**

```
$ cordova --v
/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/update-notifier/node_modules/configstore/index.js:53
            throw err;
            ^

Error: EACCES: permission denied, open    '/Users/syedtariq/.config/configstore/update-notifier-cordova.json'
You don't have access to this file.

at Error (native)
at Object.fs.openSync (fs.js:549:18)
at Object.fs.readFileSync (fs.js:397:15)
at Object.create.all.get (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/update-notifier/node_modules/configstore/index.js:34:26)
at Object.Configstore (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/update-notifier/node_modules/configstore/index.js:27:44)
at new UpdateNotifier (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/update-notifier/index.js:34:17)
at module.exports (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/update-notifier/index.js:123:23)
at checkForUpdates (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/src/cli.js:64:20)
at cli (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/src/cli.js:116:5)
at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/bin/cordova:41:1)
```

Comment: Going into to the root folder and execute the command

Comment: Destination folder -- > /usr/local/lib/node_modules/ and type the command sudo npm install -g cordova

Comment: Did as you suggested. When I run 'cordova --v' it fails. If I run with sudo it works and returns the version number. It does not matter where I execute the install command the status remains the same. I then go to my working directory and use the create command and it fails with an access error in a different file. I suspect there is something flawed with the procedure or my understanding of the instructions.

Comment: uninstall the Cordova and install Cordova once again

Comment: try cordova -v or cordova --version to get the version and also try to run as administrator

Comment: Uninstalling and re-installing does not work either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IN my case, npm had installed the node packages in `~/.npm-global/bin`. This was not in the PATH. When I added this to PATH the error was corrected. npm has a command `npm bin -g` which shows the folder where the node packages are installed. The command also pointed out that the folder was not in the path.That is how I found out the reason for the error and the correction needed.

I have seen a lot of comments on whether to use sudo. On the Mac, npm install will not complete without error unless sudo is installed. However, in the npm documentation they seem to point out that it is possible to do so. Instructions for packages generally cop out and tell you to use sudo if the npm insatll does not work.

Answer (score 2):

It may have bad residual content.

Have you tried to `sudo npm uninstall -g cordova` then `sudo npm install -g cordova` ?

Answer (score 0):

Check the version of your npm and node. 
Npm version 2.14.7 and node version 4.2.3 are stable for installing cordova and ionic. I faced many issues on cordova installation when downloading the latest release of node.

Answer (score 0):

```
$ sudo chmod -R 777 '/Users/{username}/.config/configstore/update-notifier-cordova.json'
$ No such file or directory
$ sudo chmod -R 777 '/Users/{username}/.config/'
$ sudo npm update  -g cordova
$ cordova -v 
6.0.0
```